# CSS Flexbox need accordian effect on hover

Tags: css, flexbox

I am trying to build a kind of accordion effect on hover of column field which is built using css flex-box. When i apply few styles the columns are also moving position instead of the bottom row alone. Can someone please help here. Here is the fiddle to check the issue. On hover of category the description content opens up and pushing the columns below.

https://jsfiddle.net/rc402/rx7gmbca/1/

```
.product-container {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: flex-start;
  list-style: none;
  width: 100vw;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "Open Sans', sans-serif";
  letter-spacing: -0.005em;
  color: black;
  margin: 0 8rem;
  column-gap: 3.2rem;

  .l-product {
    flex: 0 0 auto;
    margin-top: 4rem;
    margin-top: 6rem;

    img {
      height: 29.6rem;
      width: 29.6rem;
      border: 1px solid gray;
      border-radius: 2px;
    }

    .name {
      margin: 2.4rem 0 0 0;
      width: 10.8rem;
      height: 1.8rem;
      font-style: normal;
      font-weight: 700;
      font-size: 16px;
      line-height: 18px;
      text-align: left;
    }

    .role {
      margin: 1.6rem 0 0 0;
      width: 20.9rem;
      height: 1.6rem;
      font-style: italic;
      font-weight: normal;
      font-size: 14px;
      line-height: 16px;
      text-decoration-line: underline;
      text-align: left;
    }
  }

  .hide {
    display: none;
  }

  .product-description:hover+.hide {
    margin-top: 162px;
    display: block;
    width: 1280px;
    height: 526px;
    background: #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    border-radius: 2px;
  }
}
```

Also if i need to achieve same thing on click any pointers on how to do it?

Comment: i have added the solution, please check https://jsfiddle.net/pczy8rhj/1/

Comment: Do you want the content of the .hide to be fullwidth or the width of the image/column? And as it will only be shown when you hover over the category-text the content will hide immediately if you move the cursor somewhere else. Is this intended behavior?

Comment: @Aman sharma it is not working. The product 2 and product 3 are going to next row.

Comment: @Kathara, i want to content to be fuill width. On hover of each product the description should be visible in full width pushing the rows below. Ah!! thanks for pointing it out, my final intention is to make this work on click but i made a minimal fiddle so that if hover works i can convert that to click scenario.

Comment: @Kumar ok then this will not work with flexbox. The problem is that the content of .hide is inside the flexbox-element. This expands as soon as the .hide-container becomes visible. So the whole flexbox-element is expanded to that width which then pushes down the next item. I'll try to create your wanted effect, but you'll need to use absolute positioning on the .hide-container.

Comment: @kumar this is because you added `width: 1280px` to `.product-description:hover+.hide` now i have changed it visit this link again https://jsfiddle.net/94ftzgb7/1/

Comment: @kathara, thanks for checking, absolute positioning should be ok to use for me.

Comment: @AmanSharma i gave that width because i need the description to be cover full width.

Comment: @Kumar than you need to gave it position as absolute

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, **within your question**, and [not a link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254430/162698) to any other site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Kumar
it's not completely finished, but I think I created the effect you wanted:
[Codepen: CSS Flexbox need accordion effect on hover (SO)](https://codepen.io/Kathara/pen/poWeJBQ)

The main part of the magic is now happening in javascript, mainly in `initProductDesc`. I used jQuery but you could change it to vanilla of course.
You still need to adapt the initial height of the container by adding the margin.

```
$('.hide').each(function() {
    $hide = $(this);
    $hide.attr('data-initial-height', $hide.height()); // change height to include margin-top too -> outerHeigth() or something for example.
    $hide.addClass('initialized');
});
```

Does this help?

This should also work if you have to change the container width and height in responsive and it would also work with a dynamic height of the .hide-container (at least I think, not tested though).

---

**Full code:**

html (had to remove the base64 image codes -> char limit):

```
<ul class="product-container" id="">
    <li class="l-product">
        <img src="image.png" />
        <p class="name">Product 2</p>
        <p class="role product-description">category</p>
        <div class="hide">product description.</div>
    </li>
    <li class="l-product">
        <img src="image.png" />
        <p class="name">Product 5</p>
        <p class="role product-description">category</p>
        <div class="hide">product description.</div>
    </li>
    <li class="l-product">
        <img src="image.png" />
        <p class="name">Product 6</p>
        <p class="role leader-description">category</p>
        <div class="hide">product description.</div>
    </li>
    <li class="l-product">
        <img src="image.png" />
        <p class="name">Product 7</p>
        <p class="role leader-description">category</p>
        <div class="hide">product description.</div>
    </li>
    <li class="l-product">
        <img src="image.png" />
        <p class="name">Product</p>
        <p class="role product-description">category</p>
        <div class="hide">product description.</div>
    </li>
    <li class="l-product">
        <img src="image.png" />
        <p class="name">Product 8</p>
        <p class="role product-description">category</p>
        <div class="hide">product description.</div>
    </li>
    <li class="l-product">
        <img src="image.png" />
        <p class="name">Product 9</p>
        <p class="role product-description">category</p>
        <div class="hide">product description.</div>
    </li>
    <li class="l-product">
        <img src="image.png" />
        <p class="name">Product 10</p>
        <p class="role product-description">category</p>
        <div class="hide">product description.</div>
    </li>
    <li class="l-product">
        <img src="image.png" />
        <p class="name">Product 11</p>
        <p class="role product-description">category</p>
        <div class="hide">product description.</div>
    </li>
    <li class="l-product">
        <img src="image.png" />
        <p class="name">Product 12</p>
        <p class="role product-description">category</p>
        <div class="hide">product description.</div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

scss:

```
.product-container {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items: flex-start;
    list-style: none;
    width: 100vw;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: "Open Sans', sans-serif";
    letter-spacing: -0.005em;
    color: black;
    margin: 0 8rem;
    column-gap: 3.2rem;
    overflow: hidden;
    
    &, & * {
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    .l-product {
        flex: 0 0 auto;
        margin-top: 4rem;
        margin-top: 6rem;
        position: relative;
        overflow: hidden;
        padding-bottom: 0;
        transition: all 0.5s ease-in;       
    
        &.open {
            overflow: visible;
        }

        img {
            height: 29.6rem;
            width: 29.6rem;
            border: 1px solid gray;
            border-radius: 2px;
        }

        .name {
            margin: 2.4rem 0 0 0;
            width: 10.8rem;
            height: 1.8rem;
            font-style: normal;
            font-weight: 700;
            font-size: 16px;
            line-height: 18px;
            text-align: left;
        }

        .role {
            margin: 1.6rem 0 0 0;
            width: 20.9rem;
            height: 1.6rem;
            font-style: italic;
            font-weight: normal;
            font-size: 14px;
            line-height: 16px;
            text-decoration-line: underline;
            text-align: left;
        }
    
        .hide {
            display: block;
            width: 1280px;
            height: 526px;
            position: absolute;
            margin-top: 162px;
            background: #ffffff;
            border: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
            box-shadow: 0px 2px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
            border-radius: 2px;
            transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
        }
    
        &:not(.open) {
            .hide {
                &.initialized {
                    height: 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

javascript/jQuery:

```
var initProductDesc = function() {
    $('.hide').each(function() {
        $hide = $(this);
        $hide.attr('data-initial-height', $hide.height());
        $hide.addClass('initialized');
    });
    
    $('.product-description').on('click', function() {
        $thisDescription = $(this);
        $thisLi = $thisDescription.closest('.l-product');
        $thisHide = $thisDescription.siblings('.hide');
        toggledOpen = toggleClass($thisLi, 'open');
        
        if (toggledOpen) {
            $thisLi.css('padding-bottom', $thisDescription.siblings('.hide').attr('data-initial-height') + 'px');
        }
        else {
            $thisLi.css('padding-bottom', '');
        }
    });
}

var toggleClass = function($element, classname) {
    if ($element.hasClass(classname)) {
        $element.removeClass(classname);
        return false;
    }
    else {
        $element.addClass(classname);
        return true;
    }
}

$(function() {
    initProductDesc();
});
```

Comment: Thank you kathara. Do you think with small tweaks can we always show the description box starting at left 0 for all items of row instead of opening each box for each item ?

Comment: not if it's wider than the product-container. otherwise the descriptions will overlap. But otherwise... yes, you could easily change that by simply removing the absolute positioning on the description, if at some point in the responsive layout you don't wanna work with the click anymore... Or you can show all the descriptions by simply not addressing a single one when showing them.

Comment: This solution worked very well for me with few tweaks. Just having one issue is with focus. Could you help how to focus the visible description on click with padding bottom technique. I tried element.focus() and window.scrollTop(element.offset.top - 10). Both of them have jumping experience but not getting focused on the visible description.

Comment: what you need is an animation; if you're using jquery you can simply use ` $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: element.offset().top
    }, 200);` if you're not using jquery it's a bit harder but I found this article https://pawelgrzybek.com/page-scroll-in-vanilla-javascript/   and I'm sure you'll find others when googling.